# Question marked as duplicate but is a specific subcase of the duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate

The question [Replacing one column with another column in csv files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333033/replacing-one-column-with-another-column-in-csv-files) was marked as a duplicate, but the question is specifically about line-numbering. There are answers to that question that are not applicable to the broader case described by the earlier question.

- Should it still be considered a duplicate, since correct answers for the more specific case would not be considered correct answers for the more general case?
- If not, should the question title be edited to better reflect the specific question?